# rewrite rule in .htaccess that goes from root to subdirectory without displaying subdirectory name

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an old html site in the root and a new WP site in a sub-directory called new.  I just want the primary url to go straight to the /new without showing the directory name /new

Answer (score 0):

Try putting these rules in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/new%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/new%{REQUEST_URI} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/new%{REQUEST_URI} -s
RewriteRule ^ /new%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This first checks to make sure what is being requested actually exists in the `/new` directory. If it does, then it internally rewrites the URI to `/new`.

Alternatively, you can also add these rules to the vhost/server config.